# Deleting all files that start with certain pattern - Windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line

It is easy to delete files with certain extension in windows command line:

```
del *.jpg
```

I need a command that i could delete all files that DO NOT START with, somthing like this:

```
del !foo*.jpg
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Delete command doesn't have this flexibility, but you can use Remove-Item in Powershell

```
C:\PS>remove-item * -include *.dll -exclude *cal*
```

Description:

This command deletes from the current directory all files with a .dll file name extension and a name that does not include "cal". It uses the wildcard character (*) to specify the contents of the current directory. It uses the Include and Exclude parameters to specify the files to delete.

Comment: `del` is actually a alias for `remove-item` in PowerShell. so you could use `del` instead of `remove-item`.

Answer (score 1):

This powershell script will recursively delete the small backup files created by macOS, starting with ._

```
$curDir = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -force $curDir -Recurse)
{
if (($file.Extension -match '.DS_Store') -or ($file -like '._*'))
    {
    Remove-Item $file.FullName -Force | Out-Null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that with matth's you can use regex, like this:

```
$curDir = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -force $curDir -Recurse) {
  if ($file -match '^(?!foo).*?\.jpg') {
    Remove-Item $file.FullName -Force | Out-Null
  }
}
```

The operator `-match` works regexp patterns. Check [the docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7) for more matching operators.